# VarChar ZeroFill in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a row in `MYSQL` table where I want it to contain letters and numbers with a limit of 4 characters (letters or numbers). In the same time.. if somebody wanted to submit something that have 3 characters or 2. I want the rest of the data to be filled with zeros

for example:

```
23e becomes 023e
2 become 0002
1234 stays the same
123e stays the same
```

I am trying to achieve the results in MYSQL database only without using PHP. Is it possible? If it is not possible what is the code to do that in PHP?

Comment: Please don't post your questions in all CAPS. It's annoying, makes your question harder to read, and is simply rude. It also won't help you get answers any faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `char` rather than `varchar` (this has a set amount of characters).  In mysql:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (col1)
   VALUES (LPAD(?, 4, '0'))
```

Also easy to do in PHP:

```
$value = str_pad($value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: You probably don't need to do a `SELECT` subquery. `INSERT INTO t1 (col1) LPAD(?, 4, '0')` will suffice.

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible to do it while creating the new raw. so It will be done automatically just like the unsignedzerofill for the integer. Is that possible?

Comment: @shnisaka You could set up a trigger to do this, I suppose.

Comment: @shnisaka you can only use `ZEROFILL` for numeric columns

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes.. and that is my question, can we do it with letters and number columns in someway.. I do not know why MYSQL does not offer that

Answer (score -1):

Try with this PHP script:

```
<?
$YourNumber="23";
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    if(strlen($YourNumber)<4)
    {
        $YourNumber="0".$YourNumber;
    }
}
echo($YourNumber);
?>
```

Comment: Not only did the OP request "without using PHP" (which is entirely possible), but this is a bad way of doing it in PHP when `str_pad` exists.